# forms authentication works under VS development but not on iis

Tags: security, iis, authentication, forms-authentication

My asp.net app is using Forms Authentication. Running the project from the Visual Studio .NET 2008 has absolutely no problem, but it doesn't work on IIS, after clicking the Login button, the authentication code run with no error, but the Login page kept getting reloaded and reloaded.

any ideas?

tks in advance,
james

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the login page is set as the default page in iis or something?

Comment: hi awe, my defaulturl is a page inside my admin area, like I said works fine under visual studio development...I think is a infra´ issue and not code related.

Comment: ah, sorry, now I understood whats you mean...but everything is fine on IIS , I´ve checked...I think is something cookie related.